# An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'xxx'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject, .net-framework-version, .net-4.7

I am working in .Net framework 4.7.2. I am facing a problem while using NInject dependency injection resolver. I am getting the following error when trying to access NotificationController, which has no parameterless constructor:

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'NotificationController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Type 'ABC.API.Controllers.NotificationController' does not have a default constructor",
        "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
```

Here is my complete code:

INotificationService:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ABC.API.Models;

namespace ABC.API.Services
{
    public interface INotificationService
    {
        Task<bool> CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation, CancellationToken token);
        Task<bool> DeleteInstallationByIdAsync(string installationId, CancellationToken token);
        Task<bool> RequestNotificationAsync(NotificationRequest notificationRequest, CancellationToken token);
    }
}
```

NotificationHubService implementing INotificationService:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using ABC.API.Models;

namespace ABC.API.Services
{
    public class NotificationHubService : INotificationService
    {
        readonly NotificationHubClient _hub;
        readonly Dictionary<string, NotificationPlatform> _installationPlatform;
        readonly ILogger<NotificationHubService> _logger;

        public NotificationHubService(IOptions<NotificationHubOptions> options, ILogger<NotificationHubService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
                options.Value.ConnectionString,
                options.Value.Name);

            _installationPlatform = new Dictionary<string, NotificationPlatform>
            {
                { nameof(NotificationPlatform.Apns).ToLower(), NotificationPlatform.Apns },
                { nameof(NotificationPlatform.Fcm).ToLower(), NotificationPlatform.Fcm }
            };
        }

        public async Task<bool> CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation, CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation?.InstallationId) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation?.Platform) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation?.PushChannel))
                return false;

            var installation = new Installation()
            {
                InstallationId = deviceInstallation.InstallationId,
                PushChannel = deviceInstallation.PushChannel,
                Tags = deviceInstallation.Tags
            };

            if (_installationPlatform.TryGetValue(deviceInstallation.Platform, out var platform))
                installation.Platform = platform;
            else
                return false;

            try
            {
                await _hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation, token);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteInstallationByIdAsync(string installationId, CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(installationId))
                return false;

            try
            {
                await _hub.DeleteInstallationAsync(installationId, token);
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public async Task<bool> RequestNotificationAsync(NotificationRequest notificationRequest, CancellationToken token)
        {
            if ((notificationRequest.Silent &&
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationRequest?.Action)) ||
                (!notificationRequest.Silent &&
                (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationRequest?.Text)) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationRequest?.Action)))
                return false;

            var androidPushTemplate = notificationRequest.Silent ?
                PushTemplates.Silent.Android :
                PushTemplates.Generic.Android;

            var iOSPushTemplate = notificationRequest.Silent ?
                PushTemplates.Silent.iOS :
                PushTemplates.Generic.iOS;

            var androidPayload = PrepareNotificationPayload(
                androidPushTemplate,
                notificationRequest.Text,
                notificationRequest.Action);

            var iOSPayload = PrepareNotificationPayload(
                iOSPushTemplate,
                notificationRequest.Text,
                notificationRequest.Action);

            try
            {
                if (notificationRequest.Tags.Length == 0)
                {
                    // This will broadcast to all users registered in the notification hub
                    await SendPlatformNotificationsAsync(androidPayload, iOSPayload, token);
                }
                else if (notificationRequest.Tags.Length <= 20)
                {
                    await SendPlatformNotificationsAsync(androidPayload, iOSPayload, notificationRequest.Tags, token);
                }
                else
                {
                    var notificationTasks = notificationRequest.Tags
                        .Select((value, index) => (value, index))
                        .GroupBy(g => g.index / 20, i => i.value)
                        .Select(tags => SendPlatformNotificationsAsync(androidPayload, iOSPayload, tags, token));

                    await Task.WhenAll(notificationTasks);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e, "Unexpected error sending notification");
                return false;
            }
        }

        string PrepareNotificationPayload(string template, string text, string action) => template
            .Replace("$(alertMessage)", text)
            .Replace("$(alertAction)", action);

        Task SendPlatformNotificationsAsync(string androidPayload, string iOSPayload, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var sendTasks = new Task[]
            {
                _hub.SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync(androidPayload, token),
                _hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(iOSPayload, token)
            };

            return Task.WhenAll(sendTasks);
        }

        Task SendPlatformNotificationsAsync(string androidPayload, string iOSPayload, IEnumerable<string> tags, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var sendTasks = new Task[]
            {
                _hub.SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync(androidPayload, tags, token),
                _hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(iOSPayload, tags, token)
            };

            return Task.WhenAll(sendTasks);
        }
    }
}
```

NotificationController which contains INotificationService parameter in constructure

```
using ABC.API.Models;
using ABC.API.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ABC.API.Controllers
{
    public class NotificationController : ApiController
    {
        readonly INotificationService _notificationService;

        public NotificationController(INotificationService notificationService)
        {
            _notificationService = notificationService;
        }

        [HttpPut]
        [Route("installations")]
        //[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        //[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        //[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity)]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateInstallation(
            [Required] DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation)
        {
            var success = await _notificationService
                .CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(deviceInstallation, HttpContext.Current.Request.TimedOutToken);

            if (!success)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpDelete()]
        [Route("installations/{installationId}")]
        //[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        //[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        //[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity)]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteInstallation(
            [Required][FromBody] string installationId)
        {
            // Probably want to ensure deletion even if the connection is broken
            var success = await _notificationService
                .DeleteInstallationByIdAsync(installationId, CancellationToken.None);

            if (!success)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("requests")]
        //[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        //[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        //[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity)]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RequestPush(
            [Required] NotificationRequest notificationRequest)
        {
            if ((notificationRequest.Silent &&
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationRequest?.Action)) ||
                (!notificationRequest.Silent &&
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationRequest?.Text)))
                return BadRequest();

            var success = await _notificationService
                .RequestNotificationAsync(notificationRequest, HttpContext.Current.Request.TimedOutToken);

            if (!success)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is NotificationHubOptions which is declared as constructor parameter in NotificationHubService.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ABC.API.Models
{
    public class NotificationHubOptions
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then I am doing this using NInject library:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            NotificationHubOptions options = new NotificationHubOptions();
            options.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature"].ToString();
            options.Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationHubName"].ToString();

            kernel.Bind<INotificationService>().To<NotificationHubService>().InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument<NotificationHubOptions>(options);
        }
```

I had followed these links https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/webapi/dependency-interjection-in-aspnet-web-api and https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/issues/270 for NIjnect. For Push Notification Service, I followed this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms#authenticate-clients-using-an-api-key-optional. In Push notification article, they had used .Net core and they had injected the dependency through ConfigureService as below:

```
services.AddSingleton<INotificationService, NotificationHubService>();
            services.AddOptions<NotificationHubOptions>()
                .Configure(Configuration.GetSection("NotificationHub").Bind)
                .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

I could not understand what I am missing. Please also suggest how to inject ILogger to NotificationHubService constructor.

Comment: Do you set your set up container via `DependencyResolver.SetResolver` somewhere?

Comment: No, I did not set anything anywhere. I have updated the question with links I have followed.

Comment: it have been a long time since I worked with ASP MVC, but i believe you should do it somewhere.

Comment: @GuruStron I have just updated the question. Please check now

Comment: BTW any particular reasons for not using .NET Core/.NET 5?

Comment: I started to work on this app last year in April, until then I did not work much in .Net core. Also actually the app is mobile based and I was working on Xamarin for the first time. Plus I had to use Cosmos DB for gremlin API for this application, for which I had also no experience before, so I had to learn two technologies so I decided to choose .Net framework because I had years of experience in it.